# Validar si un registro (nombre) existe en la base de datos y exponer el apellido

Tags: php, laravel

Hola que tal amigos actualmente tengo el siguiente input en mi vista blade que ingresan los usuarios

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="nombre"  name="nombre" id="nombre" 
      class="form-control" value="">
```

lo solucione de la siguente forma:
'nombre'=>'required|exists:personas',

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y no expone un punto de partida sobre el cual ayudarte y sobre el cual veamos que llevas hecho, te animo a que intentes algo por tu cuenta y que edites posterior tu pregunta con mas detalles ya que de lo contrario va a quedar cerrada

Comment: listo @BetaM la edite

Comment: Aún con la edición no expones que has hecho, solo un código HTML, debes considerar tratar de armar tu consulta, evaluar si te retorna o no resultados y en concecuencia avisar al frontend

Comment: Simplemente es eso validar, hacer una consulta para validar el nombre, pero como dijo @BetaM es necesario mas informacion para saber de que manera lo estas desarrollando

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @BetaM, edite lo que he realizado, obviamente es una idea de lo que tengo en mente pero claramente no está siendo correcta, por el error mencionado

Comment: todo ello lo he realizado en mi vista blade porque necesitaria llenar el imput apellido con lo que consiga en la base de datos

Comment: Pues en realidad es muy simple, captura por medio del request el valor que manda el usuario, realiza un consulta en la cual cuentas cuantos registros con ese nombre existen, si el conteo es mayor a 1 entonces existe y mandas un mensaje y en caso contrario no existe

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar de varias maneras, una de ellas es por Request o Solicitud, la que usarás en tu controlador para verificar si existen registros: unicos, que no excedan un máximo de caracteres, etc.

creas un nuevo Request para lo que quieras validar `php artisan make:request NombrequequierasRequest`

en el archivo Request que creaste colocas las Reglas que estimes convenientes de esta forma: (TABLABD: es la tabla donde requieres que sea único tu campo 'name')

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:TABLABD',
    ];
}
```

teniendo tus reglas armadas, sólo queda utilizar tu nuevo Request en la función del controlador que quieras. Recuerda importar el archivo `App\Request\NombreDelRequest`, creo que era algo asi la ruta ajajaja.

En tu controlador quedaria algo asi:

```
    public function store(REQUESTQUECREASTE $request)
{
    try {
        $user = user::create(
            [
                'name'          => $request->name,
            ]
        );
        return redirect()->route('welcome')->with('success', 'guardado con exito');
    } catch (\Error $e) {
        return ['message' => 'error al guardar', $e];
    }
}
```

si tienes más dudas podrias echarle un vistazo a este video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOPVaNLe9Ws

la otra opción que se me ocurre es que, hagas una búsqueda a la DB por el registro que quieras que sea único, si encuentra una coincidencia podrías mandar un mensaje de alerta al cliente.

Comment: Gracias @Claudio Vallejos Silva, recien edite el intento de lo que quiero hacer, realmente no necesito validar que sea unico, necesito es saber si existen en la base de datos y en caso de existir retorne el apellido, pero muchas gracias por brindarme tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

1. Noto que no accedes de manera correcta a los valores del objeto *`$request`*, que si revisas la propia documentación en el área de [*Accessing the request*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request) te señala que la sintaxis es de esta forma:

   ```
   $request->input('nombre');
   ```

   1.1. Aunque también es posible acceder a dichos valores del *`$request`* como [propiedades dinámicas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-via-dynamic-properties) de esta forma:

   ```
   $request->nombre;
   ```
2. Lo siguiente es que la consulta planteada no cumple con lo especificado, pues si la intención es verificar si un registro existe o no; considero que debería ser de esta forma:

   2.1. Has un *`SELECT`* y con *`COUNT`* a tu entidad `persona`

   2.2. Establece un *`WHERE`* donde busques evaluar la posible igualdad del nombre recibido en el *request*

Dado lo anterior entonces tu consulta, puede pasar a lo siguiente:

```
$nombre= $request->input('nombre');
$content = DB::table('persona')->whereNombre($nombre)->count();
```

3. Ahora dentro de *`$content`* tenemos el resultado del conteo de filas producto de la consulta anterior, entonces:

   3.1. Si tenemos un valor mayor o igual a 1 significa que el registro existe y en concecuencia puedes establecer la consulta que retorne el apellido

   3.2. De lo contrario el registro no existe

Dado lo anterior, entonces tu consulta puede terminar de esta forma:

```
if ($content === 0) {
    return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'Sin registros existentes']);
}
return DB::table('persona')->whereNombre($nombre)->value('apellido');
```

Dado que no te interesa la fila completa sino únicamente el apellido, entonces te puedes valer del [método **`value`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table)

Comment: Finalmente lo resolví validando en el request si existe el registro, ya que me era confuso pasar los mensajes de error la vista, por cuanto no manejo bien esa parte, gracias por sus sugerencias

Comment: Entonces considera publicar tu solución

Comment: Listo @BetaM alli coloque la solución para el que lo necesite

Comment: Cómo bien ya sabes la solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta

Comment: Además tu solución está en todo caso incompleta, como consultas ahí el apellido?

Comment: Hola gracias por las sugerencias, la tomaré en cuenta para futuras preguntas, en cuanto a devolver el apellido ese tema no lo he resuelto según vi tu programación lo contempla pero como te comenté no sabria como incluir en la vista ese datos, aun me falta mucho por aprender de momento estoy investigando como resolverlo gracias @BetaM